# Determine the window size turtle python setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

In Python 3+, I am trying to run `turtle.setup(400, 500)` but it is not working.

There is no reference named `setup`.

How can I use the screen setup in Python 3?

Answer (score 5):

There are (at least) three options depending on how you import turtle.  Going from worst to best:

Option 1:

```
from turtle import *

setup(400, 500)
```

Option 2:

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(400, 500)
```

Option 3:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(400, 500)
```

If these don't work for you, then update your question with more information about the environment under which you're running Python/turtle.